# Error loading a png with cv2 - resulting array is null

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to load the image below, in `.png` format, using `cv2`.

However, when I do so the resulting array is completely empty.

[image]

```
a = cv2.imread(img_path)
b = a != 0
b.any()
```

Result: `False`

What is going on?

I am using Python 3 and opencv 3.4.2.

Comment: print "a" shape. and check the path

Comment: @Miki `a.shape = (240, 450, 3)`, path is correct

Comment: So the image is loaded correctly. "b" just results to be false

Comment: @Miki but how can that be? The image is clearly not constant

Comment: could it be that the "white" pixels are just black but transparent? and when you load them, you get BGR and not BGRA and then everything is black (0)?

Comment: @api55 that could very well be the case. How can I load the alpha channel properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your logo is all black. The white parts look white because the background where you opened it is white. When you load an image with OpenCV [`imread`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.5/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56) function it uses by default [`cv2.IMREAD_COLOR`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.5/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gga61d9b0126a3e57d9277ac48327799c80af660544735200cbe942eea09232eb822) which will give you a BGR image and drops the alpha channel. So in this case all 0.

Now, if you try with [`cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.5/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gga61d9b0126a3e57d9277ac48327799c80aeddd67043ed0df14f9d9a4e66d2b0708) you will get the alpha, and you will see that it returns True just remember that when alpha is **0 it is actually transparent and 255 opaque** in OpenCV (from 0% to 100%)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

a=cv2.imread('a.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED )
b=a!=0
print(b.any())
```

And to show that the background is black and transparent and the logo is solid and black, lets put the solid info white:

```
a=cv2.imread('a.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED )
a[a[:,:,3] == 255] = 255
b=a!=0
print(b.any())

# lets omit the alpha channel for now
cv2.imwrite('o.png', a[:,:,0:3])
cv2.imshow('a',a)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

With this as result:

[image]